# Turn off doze mode pragmatically

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-doze

The android Marshmallow has a new built in doze feature that shuts down background processes after some time. How to resolve this by simply checking if the device is waking up from this doze event and then relaunching the scheduler process (comparing the timestamps to see how much time has passed).

PLease Help!!

Answer (score 0):

> that shuts down background processes after some time.

That is not what doze does. When doze kicks in, a number of restrictions are applied to the app (read [here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#restrictions) which ones exactly) but the app is not shut down or killed, it will keep running.

The aim of doze is to restrict an app's capabilities in order to prevent draining the battery, not to stop apps from running.